# Get All Hours of The Day (in date format) from 9am tp 11pm and Save within an array in Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, date, calendar, nsdate

I need to get all the remaining hours of the day starting from whatever the current hour is until 11pm and save it in an array in a date format. Here is what I have written so far:

```
var sortedTime: [Date] = {

    let today = Date()
    var sortedTime: [Date] = []

    (0..<14).forEach {
        sortedTime.append(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today)!)            
    }

    return sortedTime
}()
```

In the code I have: `(0..<14).forEach {` This is giving me the next 14 hours but thats not what I need; I need to make sure the hours I get are between 9am and 11pm. How would I be able to set this limit?

Comment: Use `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)` or another way to set a "mignight" or directly the `9am` one, and iterate from it instead of `Date()`?

Comment: I need to start from the current hour. So if it is 3pm now; I need to get the hours from 3pm to 11pm. If the current hour is 6am now; then I need to get the hours from 8am to 11pm. So if I set 9am instead of Date() I wouldnt be able to start from the current hour.

Comment: Also; how would I set it to midnight? and how would that help with stopping at 11pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access .hour for any calender its in a 24h format. so you need to something like this:

```
let today = Date()
var sortedTime: [Date] = []
var calender = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
calender.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let currentHour = calender.component(.hour, from: today)
(0...(24-currentHour)).forEach {
    guard let newDate = calender.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today) && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) != 0,
        calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) <= 23 else {
        return
    }
    //convert date into desired format
    sortedTime.append(newDate)
}
```

Comment: That worked; except it also gives me 12am. So I edited and added this line to exclude 12am: `&& calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) != 0`. Can you edit your answer to include this so i can choose it as the answer? What is the locale for here by the way?

Comment: Also, do you know how I can provide a one hour range? So that I can have 2pm to 3pm , 3pm to 4pm, 4pm to 5pm, ... ?

Comment: @Farhadam en_US_POSIX local is USA.
"Also, do you know how I can provide a one hour range?" what do you mean exeactly by this? just add 1 hour every time? like `value: $0 +1`

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear about what I was asking. I actually figured it out, I wanted it to look like the screenshot I attached in my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255664/change-tableview-cells-by-choosing-different-cells-from-collectionview-which-is I just did two variables and then showed them in the labels next to each. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Farhadam ahh okay i see! glad i could help

Comment: Do you know how I can change this code so I can get all the hours of the day regardless of the current hour? So basically I want to get these hours in order regardless of what the time in the day is: 8am,9am,10am,...,11pm

Comment: @Farhadam make the foreach loop from 0-24 (all hours). In the foreach loop you can exclude/include every hour you want

Comment: Yea, I do this but the start of hour in the output is from the current hour; while I want the first one to be 10am regardless of what the current hour is. Is there a way to sort the output in order of hour regardless of the current hour? (0...24).forEach {
            guard let newDate = calender.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today),
                calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) >= 10
                    && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) <= 23
                    && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) != 0 else {
                        return
        }

Comment: So for example; with the above code; its giving me output of hours starting with 15 (15, 16, 17, ...) while I want it to start with 10. But its using 15 because the current hour from "today" is 15.

Comment: @Farhadam Okay now i got it. So you will need to run your for loop with another date. for example: `let modifiedToday = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 10, of: Date())`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you @esemusa