# Change tableView Cells by choosing different cells from collectionView which is the Header of tableview

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I have the collectionView as my tableview header. Now I need to change the cells of the tableView depending on the cell I choose from the collection view. How do I do this from didselect of the collectionview?

[image]

This is my tableview:

```
extension DeliveryTimeVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedTimeFrom.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//        print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.DeliveryTimeCell, for: indexPath) as! DeliveryTimeCell

        cell.configureCell(timeFrom: sortedTimeFrom[indexPath.row], timeTo: sortedTimeTo[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}
```

And this is my collectionView:

```
extension DeliveryTimeVC : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedDates.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.DeliveryDateCell, for: indexPath) as! DeliveryDateCell

        cell.configureCell(date: sortedDates[indexPath.row], day: sortedDay[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.DeliveryDateCell, for: indexPath) as! DeliveryDateCell


    }
```

and this is how I call the header:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableHeaderView = collectionView
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

}
```

here is my sortedTimeFrom:

```
var sortedTimeFrom: [Date] = {


    let today = Date()
    var sortedTime: [Date] = []
    var calender = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    calender.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    let currentHour = calender.component(.hour, from: today)

    (0...(24-currentHour)).forEach {

        guard let newDate = calender.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today),
            calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) >= 10
                && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) <= 22
                && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) != 0
                && calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) >= (currentHour+3)  else {
                return
        }
        //convert date into desired format
        sortedTime.append(newDate)
    }


    return sortedTime
}()
```

Comment: Respond to `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` and then update the datasource for the tableView and reload it.

Comment: How would I write that within the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` ?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code for the tableView and datasource.

Comment: @koen I just edited my post and included my codes.

Comment: And what about `sortedTimeFrom` ? That's what needs to change, correct?

Comment: Yes I need to change that so it is using another variable. Lets Call it; sortedTimeFromAgain

Comment: @koen if it helps; I just edited my post with sortedTimeFrom included. I have another one (call it sortedTimeFromAgain) that I want to use that instead when I select a different cell in the collectionView

Comment: You could use a property `var dataSource = sortedTimeFrom`, and then use that for your table. And when you click on a `collectionViewCell`, you change it to `dataSource = sortedTimeFromAgain` and then call `tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested in Xcode.*

Create a property inside `DeliveryTimeVC`:

```
var dataSource: [Date] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = sortedTimeFrom
    ///... other stuff
}
```

Then, inside your tableView dataSource methods access that value:

```
extension DeliveryTimeVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.DeliveryTimeCell, for: indexPath) as! DeliveryTimeCell

        cell.configureCell(timeFrom: dataSource[indexPath.row], timeTo: sortedTimeTo[indexPath.row] 

        return cell
    }
}
```

Finally, inside `didSelect` do something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   dataSource = sortedTimeAgain
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This is not working on my end. A lot of errors in the code when I type in xcode

Comment: Yes, I left some parts open, because you have not shared your logic there. Those are for you to fill in.

Comment: For example; the line you wrote: var dataSource: [SortedTime] = sortedTimeFrom , the last part doesnt work in xcode: "= sortedTimeFrom"

Comment: Not sure what logic you are referring to. Im simply trying to change from var sortedTimeFrom to var sortedTimeFromAgain... there is no additional logic

Comment: I have edited my answer and removed the `SortedTime` struct - maybe it is more clear now?

Comment: This line of yours: "var dataSource: [Date] = sortedTimeFrom" When I write that; it gives an error. It doesnt seem to be correct this part " = sortedTimeFrom" are you sure this line is the correct way of writing it?

Comment: Cannot use instance member 'sortedTimeFrom' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: You don't show `sortedTimeTodayFrom` in your question.

Comment: So maybe you need to assign `dataSource` in `viewDidLoad`, see updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203999/discussion-between-koen-and-farhadam).

Comment: didnt know there was a chat feature - pretty cool. Just messaged you there